# Installing TBB w/Sophos

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, windows, blocked-services, web-proxy

I have been using TBB for over a year now. I am a student who values privacy very much, and I install Tor on every computer I use. However, my school is updating their computers and many of them use something called "Sophos Protection." I can download TBB without a problem, but whenever I try to launch TBB, Sophos displays a message saying that it's a proxy and thus blocks TBB.

Most (I'd say 80 to 90%) of the computers in my school use this program. Is there some sort of workaround that would allow me to use TBB w/o this obnoxious blocker? Please help.

Relevant Info:
--My school uses Windows 7 computers.
--I do not have any sort of admin/root access.